# Alternative to `x-amz-website-redirect-location` in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I would like to host a website in Google Cloud Storage, where the root points to a certain folder (basically it redirects to the `/en/` folder, the default language).

I can accomplish this in Amazon S3 using the `x-amz-website-redirect-location` header. But according to [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/migrating), that header is not available in Google Cloud Storage.

Is there a clean way to do this? Or should I add an index.html file in the root with a [meta refresh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) element?

Comment: You'd have to use a meta refresh. There's no way to have GCS objects that  send back redirects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by @jterrace it is not possible to redirect using a header right now. The solution is to include a meta refresh element:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=/en/">
    </head>
</html>
```